# Bootstrap 4.3.1 dropdown login form redirect upon success

Tags: authentication, dropdown

I am building a site where users can login via a Bootstrap Dropdown, i did have it working, it would log user in and refresh the whole page with login session BUT if user entered wrong creds it wouldn't stay open and alert them.  I got around this by putting the login form in an iframe in the dropdown but it's no longer starting the session - any ideas please?  I'm trying to not be vague so here is the code in the iframe and the actual URL below that - thank you :)

```
<div class="header_login_form_dropdown">Login</div>
  <form name="login" action="" method="post" class="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="login_form_dropdown" for="lopc_username">Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="lopc_username" placeholder="email@company.com" name="lopc_username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="login_form_dropdown" for="lopc_password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="lopc_password" name="lopc_password">
    </div>

      <a href="https://littleorangeprinting.co.uk/2021/forgot_password.php" target="_parent" style="font-size: 12px; margin-left: 3px;">Forgot password</a>
      
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary login_btn">LOGIN</button>
      
      <div style="padding:15px 0 15px 0;  border-top: 2px solid #eee; font-size: 14px; color: #696969">
      New customer?  <a href="https://littleorangeprinting.co.uk/2021/register.php" target="_parent">Register here</a>
      </div>
      
       
      <?php
      

      
if (isset($_POST['submit']))

{

include('../265451/92631043.php');

$lopc_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['lopc_username']);
$lopc_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,(md5($_POST['lopc_password'])));
$lopc_last_login = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$query = "SELECT * FROM lopc_reg_users WHERE lopc_username = '$lopc_username' AND lopc_password = '$lopc_password' ";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) 

{
    
    $_SESSION['lopc_username'] = $_POST['lopc_username'];
    $lopc_username = $_SESSION['lopc_username'];
    
    $query2 = "UPDATE lopc_reg_users SET lopc_last_login = '$lopc_last_login' WHERE lopc_username = '$lopc_username' ";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$query2);

    //header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    ?>
      <script>
            window.parent.location.reload();
      </script>
      <?php
    exit;
}
    else
    {
        echo '<div class="login_error">Username or password does not exist.</div>';
    }
      
}
      ?>
      
  </form>
```

https://littleorangeprinting.co.uk/2021

Login:     test@test.com
Pass:      testing4321

Comment: If you want the user to be notified of errors without reloading the page, then you’ll need to do the form submission via AJAX.

Comment: Ahhhhh, I feared this!  thank you, I will have to do that yes